# Why is my bootstrap styles in StyleBundle not loaded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, styles, bundle

I'm trying to add bootstrap styles to an existing project using StyleBundle. The other styles in the same bundle works, but the bootstrap styles are not. Here is my bundle:

```
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
            "~/Content/boostrap/boostrap.css",
            "~/Content/boostrap/boostrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/boostrap/boostrap-theme.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
            "~/Content/Site.css"));

@Styles.Render("~/bundles/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

In Google Chrome > F12 > Network > Stylesheets tab, I don't see the bootstrap styles, but I can see font-awesome.css and site.css styles.

However, if I drag-n-drop the styles into the index.html page header, I can see them.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I don't see any error in the browser either. Is there anything special in bootstrap I missed?

Comment: I would try move bootstrap.css to same folder as font-awesome.css just to make sure that this is not some kind of permission error. Overall I agree, that optimization lib with its silent fails annoys a bit. On the other hand, is the problem exact as you wrote, for example ain't those css files with min.css endings, as in debug mode they won't be included?

Answer (score 3):

Your code states: ../boostrap/... you should be using /bootstrap/. So a simple typo.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I never figured out what the problem here is. However, I recreated the project and so far I never run into this problem again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You made a typing error in your code.
In the following lines the location is boostrap.

            `bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/css").Include(
            "~/Content/boostrap/boostrap.css",
            "~/Content/boostrap/boostrap-responsive.css",
            "~/Content/boostrap/boostrap-theme.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
            "~/Content/Site.css"));`

Comment: After having this very same error, I am considering punting on the Bundling inside MVC and using Web Essential to perform that function because it is not dependent on the string name.